# What's this Ruby syntax?

Tags: ruby

I just read the following code:

```
class Dir
   def self.create_uniq &b  ### Here, & should mean b is a block
      u = 0
      loop do
      begin
         fn = b[u]   ### But, what does b[u] mean? And b is not called.
         FileUtils.mkdir fn
         return fn
      rescue Errno::EEXIST
         u += 1
      end
    end
    io
  end
end
```

I put my confusion as comment in the code.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Defining method with `&b` on the end allows you to use block passed to the method as `Proc` object.

Now, if you have `Proc` instance, `[]` syntax is shorthand to `call`:

```
p = Proc.new { |u| puts u }
p['some string']
# some string
# => nil
```

Documented here -> [`Proc#[]`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Proc.html#method-i-5B-5D)

Comment: According to the [Ruby Style Guide](https://github.com/bbatsov/ruby-style-guide) you should *"Prefer `proc.call()` over `proc[]` or `proc.()` for both lambdas and procs."*

Answer (score 1):

The & prefix operator allow a method to capture a passed block as a named parameter. e.g:

```
def wrap &b
  3.times(&b)
  print "\n"
end
```

now if you call above method like this:

```
wrap { print "Hi " }
```

then output would be:

```
Hi Hi Hi
```